# I want to use EBImage package but it says it is not available for my version of R

Tags: image-processing, install.packages

> Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘EBImage’ is not available (for R version 3.2.4 Revised)

what to do now any help,please guide me.

Comment: Can you please mark the below answer as solution and mark this question resolved?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Install the latest release of R, then get the latest version of Bioconductor by starting R and entering the commands

```
install.packages("BiocManager") 
BiocManager::install("EBImage")
library(EBImage)
```

Install specific packages, e.g., “GenomicFeatures” and “AnnotationDbi”, with

```
BiocManager::install(c("GenomicFeatures", "AnnotationDbi"))
```

Answer (score 19):

[*EBImage*](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/EBImage) is distributed as part of the Bioconductor project. To install the package use

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("EBImage")
```