# Import multiple PNG images

Tags: r, image, image-processing, import

How to import multiple png images? I am using R v3.4.1.

`EBImages` and `readImages` packages not available in this version

```
library(png)

img_train <- list.files(path = "file path",pattern = ".png",
                        all.files = TRUE,
                       full.names = TRUE, no.. = TRUE)
list_of_images <- lapply(img_train, readPNG)
```

To convert into matrix

```
image_matrix <- do.call('cbind', lapply(list_of_images, as.numeric))
```

If anyone has a better solution, please share!

Comment: NO NEED TO SHOUT !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EBImage* is available from the Bioconductor repository, for installation instructions see the answer to [I want to use EBImage package but it says it is not available for my version of R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37411197/2792099)
. You can then use the `readImage` function to import multiple images as an array or a list.

```
library("EBImage")

img_train <- list.files(path = "file path", pattern = ".png", 
                        all.files = TRUE,full.names = TRUE,no.. = TRUE)

## image array
img_array <- readImage(img_train)

## image list
img_list <- lapply(img_train, readImage)
```