# Unable to install EBImage package in r

Tags: r, face-recognition

Unable to install `EBImage` in R... Getting

> Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘EBImage’ is not available for R version 3.5.0

Please help on the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to use EBImage package but it says it is not available for my version of R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222603/i-want-to-use-ebimage-package-but-it-says-it-is-not-available-for-my-version-of)

Answer (score 0):

EBImage is a part of [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/packages/EBImage) project. So for installation you'll need to install [BiocManager](https://cran.r-project.org/package=BiocManager) first. See [installation guide](https://github.com/aoles/EBImage#installation).

Ane yes, there is an older version for R 3.5, just run:

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
# maybe you'll need to specify the last version for R 3.5:
# BiocManager::install(version = "3.8")
BiocManager::install("EBImage")
```

See [documentation](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/EBImage.html).

For lower version of R there is also a possibility to install it with another command:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("EBImage")
```

Comment: Thanks for you response Petr...However i have tried same thing but getting below mentioned error.(cannot open compressed file 'EBImage/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory')

Comment: @Shailendramishra Oh, so please try to run `source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")` and then `biocLite("EBImage")` and let me know what happens.

Comment: Below is the warning Message.....In addition: Warning messages:
1: 'biocLite' is deprecated.
Use 'BiocManager::install' instead.
See help("Deprecated") 
2: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 707829 != reported length 12726191
3: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
4: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
  cannot open compressed file 'EBImage/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'